# Error while access local machine outlook emails from web application

Tags: c#, com, outlook, mapi

I have made a C#.net application to access all my folders and emails from my local machine outlook.
To make this application I have used COM object, my application is working fine with my local machine using link localhost:51514/mymail/list

Sample code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
ns.Logon("abc@mydomain.com","password", true, true);

Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

MapModel.InboxFolder = app.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
MapModel.CategoryList = SetCategoryList(MapModel.InboxFolder);
```

but when I put this application on server and then try to access my email I get error at runtime.

> ERROR: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

The requirement of my project : where ever I open my application, it should access all emails from Microsoft outlook on that machine and list emails in my application.

seeking for some help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you expect server-side code to access client-side software?

Comment: Hello Steen, I thought may be it is possible because using COM object which give full access to outlook and I have login detail as well. But really is it not possible ? or is not there any API available to do this?

Comment: To access the local instance of Outlook, your code needs to run on that machine locally, which means it must be VB or JAva script running inside IE (since only IE supports COM objects) and your site must be trusted to be able to create and access local COM objects.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks for your reply, is it possible with Redemption http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm

Comment: It is possible, but Redemption must be installed locally, you will need to move your code to the client side VB or Java Script, your side must be in the trusted list, and the bitness of Outlook and IE must match.